# convert const char* to int

Tags: c, csv, io

I read from CSV file with 4 column (integers). The read function works but when I try to insert char values into array (of integers) return this error

> a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type
>   "float"

I try to use `atoi` but return list of 0000, 1111 etc.
Can you suggest me some solution?
the code:

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return (tok);
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{

    FILE *pf=fopen("Trajectory_1.csv","r");         
    char line[1024];

    if(pf==NULL){
        printf("ERROR MESSAGE");
        exit(1);
    }
    int x=0;
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),pf)){
        char* tmp=strdup(line);
        printf("%s",getfield(tmp,1));
        t_h[x]=getfield(tmp,1);
        free(tmp);
        x++;
    }
    fclose(pf);
}
```

in this case only the first column

**EDIT**
the code will be

```
double getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ","); //comam separator
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return (atof(tok));
    }
    return NULL;
}

FILE *pf=fopen("//home//user//Documenti//Bello//Dataset1//Trajectories//Trajectory_1.csv","r"); //rivedere
    char line[1024];

    if(pf==NULL){
        printf("ERR MSG");  // I change this like William suggest
        exit(1);
    }

int x=0;

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),pf)){

        double d=getfield(line,1)); // I did not understand

    }
    fclose(pf);
```

Comment: ` printf("ERROR MESSAGE");` is always wrong.  Errors belong on stderr.  Try `pf = open( path, "r");  if( pf == NULL ) { perror( path ); ... `

Comment: @WilliamPursell "Error Message" it's only for this question, I have appropriate message

Comment: Sure, but you're printing it to the wrong stream.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok I will change in my code thanks

Comment: I don't see a declaration of `t_h`, so I assume it is an array of floats.  You can't make that assignment without an explicit cast, but the explicit cast is wrong.  More importantly, you are returning the address of a local variable from getfield, and that value is useless after the function returns.  What are you trying to do?  I suspect you want to call `strtod` in getfield and return that value.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I pasted only the code relevant to the question, t_h is declared. I want to put csv cell value into array, you suggest to use strtod?

Answer (score 0):

`getField` is to return the floating point value of the CSV column identified by `num`. `getField` is called each time with a new line to parse.

Then the function should return a double, namely `return(atof(tok));` (and be declared as `double getfield(..`);

You must remove your print statement, as it calls `getField` but getField modifies the string (through strtok). Also there seems no need to call `strdup`; just let getField work on `line`.

Note: I am not a `strtok` specialist but the second call (in the for statement) may be wrong and may also need the comma as a terminator.